# How can I tell why my query is running so slow?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query that is taking a lot longer then usual, and I cannot tell if it is stuck.

The query is something like this:

```
INSERT XXXXXX WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT * FROM YYYYYY with (NOLOCK)
WHERE ZZZZZZZZ = 1
```

This will insert hundreds of millions of rows.  I have an index on ZZZZZZZZ.

There are no blocking sessions.  When I check sys.dm_exec_requests, it shows that the last wait type is **PAGEIOLATCH_SH**  I'm not sure what this means, except that it has something to do with I/O.

sys.dm_exec_sessions shows the status is RUNNING, but sp_who2 shows it as SUSPENDED.

I tried to see if the table is growing, but when I call sp_spaceused XXXXXX, I keep getting the same values.

What else can I do?

**UPDATE:**

With the help of the answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687568/how-can-i-tell-if-a-long-running-query-is-stuck), I have found that there is [an I/O issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687568/how-can-i-tell-if-a-long-running-query-is-stuck/3687620#3687620), and that my query [is resulting in an average of about 600 records being inserted per minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687568/how-can-i-tell-if-a-long-running-query-is-stuck/3687764#3687764)).

**What is my next step?**

What can I do before I start to assume that my disk is going bad?

Answer (score 1):

The query is running, the PAGEIOLATCH_SH is typical when doing a lot of inserts as it is a wait on the disk subsystem. The index is actually hindering performance as the index gets an insert for every insert to the table.

100's of millions are a lot of records and will take some time, how long has it been running?

Comment: The index is on YYYYYY.  Not XXXXXX.  The insert used to take about 15 hours, but it is going on 26 now.

Comment: My mistake, there are no indexes on XXXXXX?

Comment: Also, I like using Activity monitor to watch the process.

Comment: There are no enabled indexes in XXXXXXX.  There is a non clustered index, but I disable it before the insert. Again, though, this insert is going a lot slower than it used to.  That is what I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2005 or 2008, I would definitely run the sp_whoisactive script developed by SQL MVP Adam Mechanic.  It's basically sp_who/sp_who2 on steroids and should give you all the info you need.

http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry27502.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this.  I actually have an earlier version that I am using already.  I just don't know all that much about how to read it.

Comment: fair enough.  As a starting point, I would check it a couple minutes apart and make sure the read/write counters are increasing.  At least you will be able to tell whether it's actually going or stuck.